# Violin Plot Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, statistics

I am trying to find source code to create [violin plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot#cite_note-0) in Matlab. Functionality does not exist in the statistics toolbox nor does a simple Google result in anything useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [DISTRIBUTIONPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23661-distribution-plot). I apologize for the name: I called the function like that because I didn't know that they were otherwise known as violin plots at the time.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! You may want to update the file to call it violin plots at the appropriate spot. I bet I am not the only one looking for this functionality.

Comment: Nice! I was looking around for Matlab violin plots, too.

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Thanks for the suggestion. I have changed the title of the submission.